# Broken mysql-server on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation, mysql

I'm attempting to install mysql-server into a fresh ubuntu:20.04 container and it is breaking during install. Some highlights about what I'm seeing are...

After creating a new container running 20.04 and updating it...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfreetype6
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmecab2 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common
  mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
Suggested packages:
  libdata-dump-perl libipc-sharedcache-perl libwww-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmecab2 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common mysql-server
  mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
0 upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 32.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 264 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 [7496 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-core-8.0 amd64 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [4521 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-8.0 amd64 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [22.0 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libevent-core-2.1-7 amd64 2.1.11-stable-1 [89.1 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 amd64 2.1.11-stable-1 [7372 B]

...

emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################| 

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-5) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.22-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
2022-08-02T20:03:15.538844Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log.
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-08-02 20:03:18 UTC; 22ms ago
    Process: 3174 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3182 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 3182 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server shutdown complete"
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.46-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.17) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Looking into `/var/log/mysql/error/log` we see this:

```
2022-08-02T20:03:24.261621Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 3779
2022-08-02T20:03:24.273173Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-02T20:03:24.419056Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012962] [InnoDB] The redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo5 size 2531328 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size
2022-08-02T20:03:24.419154Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-08-02T20:03:24.798345Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-02T20:03:24.798671Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-02T20:03:24.798720Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-02T20:03:24.799469Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
```

over and over again. Having tried many many permutations of how to fix broken installs I'm getting a wee bit frustrated, esp as this has broken our entire dev shop as we are developing on 20.04 and all the mysql instances on all the dev containers were force upgraded over the weekend from version 5 to version 8, and version 8 is currently uninstallable on 20.04 and on 22.04.

One big question, is whether anyone else is having this problem? Does anyone have any ideas about what is going on?

Comment: When you say “container” are you referring to Docker? Or are you installing in a VM of some sort?

Comment: I am installing it on an lxd container. The global host is running 20.04 and our devs have 20.04 containers running on it.